# ISO date formats to wrong day

Tags: php, time, iso

Short question but I can't get my finger on it. This piece of code:

```
$date = '2015-12-08T00:00:00+01:00';
echo date('D', strtotime($date));
```

returns Mon while

```
$date = '2015-12-08T00:00:00';
echo date('D', strtotime($date));
```

returns Tue. Why is that? The +01:00 is for the timezone, but that should not affect the day in my opinion.

Comment: "The +01:00 is for the timezone, but that should not affect the day in my opinion." Why not? At my next local midnight (GMT) it'll be Tuesday here, but it'll  still be Monday in America. What timezone are you in? (Or, more specifically, what timezone is your PHP environment set to be in? `echo(date_default_timezone_get());`)

Comment: I am in Europe/Amsterdam time. GMT +1. So strtotime depends on the time of the server? And would that mean that date('D', strtotime(2015-12-08)); sometimes monday returns, and sometimes tuesday?

Comment: If I set my PHP timezone to 'Europe/Amsterdam', I get the result 'Tue' for your first piece of code. Are you *sure* your timezone is set how you think it is? Did you run `echo(date_default_timezone_get());`?

Answer (score 1):

First I've looked up that 08-12-2015 is in fact a `Tuesday`, so now we know the first one is incorrect.

PHP's `date()` is an Unix timestamp according to their own docs.

My belief is that adding the +1 as a timezone triggers the calculation to the +0 timezone (UTC) when asking for the day of the week and therefore returns 23:00 on monday as the current UTC time.

You can specify the timezone before executing the rest of the code: `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');`

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam'); //this is an example of a +1 timezone, choose one from http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php
$date = '2015-12-08T00:00:00+01:00';
echo date('D', strtotime($date) );
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It fixes my problem. So from what I understand is that the Unix timestamp depends on your serversettings. Learned something again today.

Comment: Well that is logical, because code needs a reference point for time: your server time, you can let it sync with a timeserver of course.

Answer (score 1):

[`strtotime`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) will parse your date string using the supplied time zone or using the **default timezone** if unspecified. We can't see from the code you've posted what time zone your server is configured to, but once the date is parsed and converted to your time zone, the time may legitimately occur in the previous day, hence why you're seeing `'Mon'`.

Either supply a time zone in the `strtotime` call via the `now` argument or set one globally with [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).